# Seeming to set a 1-directional databind even though it should be bidirectional

Tags: dart, polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

Been working with 2 files:  *my_ajax_fetcher.data/html* with the data as follows:

*my_ajax_fetcher.dart*

```
@HtmlImport('my_ajax_fetcher.html')
library webserver_ajax.lib.iron_ajax;

import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/iron_ajax.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/iron_request.dart';

///Uses [IronAjax]
@PolymerRegister('my-ajax-fetcher')
class IronAjaxSample extends PolymerElement {

  @property
  String f_name;

  @property
  String l_name;

  @property
  int identification;


  //IronAjax ia = querySelector('myAjaxId');

  IronAjaxSample.created() : super.created(){
    print("created.");
    //ia.generateRequest();
  }


  @reflectable
  void handleResponse ( [CustomEventWrapper cew, IronRequest ir] ){
    print("handle response fired");
    var data = ir.response;
    f_name = data["f_name"];
    l_name = data["l_name"];
    identification = data["id"];

    print("$f_name $l_name: $identification");
  }
}
```

*my_ajax_fetcher.html*

```
<dom-module id="my-ajax-fetcher">
    <template>

        <iron-ajax id="myAjaxId" auto
          url="http://localhost:8675/test_server/v1/users/35"
          handle-as="json"
          on-response="handleResponse" ></iron-ajax>

        <div>First Name: {{f_name}}</div>
        <div>Last Name:  {{l_name}}</div>
        <div>Student ID:  {{identification}}</div>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

And when the ajax call finishes it will call `handleResponse` which will set `f_name`, `l_name`, `identification` variables.  The issue is that i see the variables are set in the last line of `handleResponse`.

It doesn't set the markup according to say:   `First Name: Frank` at all, it is just empty.  I have determined that for some reason, `handleResponse` is a different scope than the other functions.  How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dart you always need to use `set(...)` or any other method provided by Polymer to update data.

```
set('f_name', data["f_name"]);
set('l_name', data["l_name"]);
set('identification', data["id"]);
```

In JavaScript this is not necessary for fields of a Polymer element, only for properties of complex types (custom classes, collections, ...)

See also

- https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/properties#list-mutation-methods
- https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/data-binding-syntax#path-change-notification
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_autonotify
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/autonotify_observe

Comment: This is the right answer.  My way seems to make sense, but it doesnt actually work in practice.   i guess it is because even though it is changed, it doesnt necessarily fire the on changed notifier that the front end uses.  I know i have used it my way before and it works.  Maybe it was back in 0.5 or something.

Comment: In 0.5 this was quite different. See also the links I added to my question.  Vittorio Ballestras autonotify packages make this easier in Dart Polymer.